# .Net Projects Integration and reference to those doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, ranorex

I have more than one .Net projects to work and i want to reference these all projects into one integrated project and add them as a reference in this project and want to run any method or function from this integrated project.So i have added all these projects in the same solution in the directory and added them to the solution and added as a reference.
Now My question
I havent converted those projects to class library as i want the main method to be there to kickoff that function from my integrated project ,if i make it class library will i still be able to access that main method???

I did add those projects reference and made them to class library and also as exe,but in both the cases , when i did import them ,but when i try to call those functions,it doesnt create an instance and doesnt show any options in intelligence,on top of that,once i try to build it back again,it throws an error "**The type or namespace name could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

Can someone please answer them !!!!

Comment: So you “added all these projects in the same solution” but “havent converted those projects to class library”. So what did you add them as?

Comment: i have added all of them to my solution and added them in the reference directory

Answer (score 1):

Internally there is little difference between a .NET exe and a .NET DLL. For most purposes a .NET .exe is just a .NET dll with some data saying "this class has the main function". It is one of those things they copied really well from Java and improoved upon.

There might be secondary differences (I am not sure the .exe provides full COM/.NET interop support, for example). But for most purposes, you can use a Compiled .NET exe like a compiled .NET dll. Including putting it into the references of a 3rd project.

The main issue here is that only the compiled code in the propert directory is considered. Especially if you still plan on working on those backend References, you need to be aware if you referenced the Debug or Release version of the .dll/.exe

Comment: SO,if i add those projects as .dll ,when i import them in my integrated project,how will i be able to kickoff those projects.

Comment: You use the dll/exe the same way you use the dll wich are automatically given as reference to any new project. The only thing special is that you have to manually add them via Browse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx Beyond that Intellisense and Autocompletion will pick up the Namespace and Class names as they do with the "System.Windows.Forms.dll" or "mscorlib.dll" (contains stuff like object).